# Designing a context free grammar for a language

Tags: context-free

Design a grammar for the language

$$F = \{x^a y^b zx^b y^a\mid a, b\geq 1\}$$

I'm trying to get a stronger grasp of designing grammars for languages. A thorough explanation of how to design the grammar for this language would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Construct a word of the language $F$ starting from the endpoints and iteratively appending new terminals at the center. The final terminal to be generated will be $z$.

Answer (score -1):

The following is a context-free grammar to describe $F$:

$$S\to xS'y$$

$$ S'\to xS'y\mid yS^{''}x$$

$$S^{''}\to yS^{''}x\mid z$$